# Thesis with visible project method in bibliography

Tags: software-development, project-management-style

I'm writing a thesis about engineering a new product that consists of hardware and software (cloud, mobile, embedded).

My lecturer said i should use the problem solving cycle, we wanted use the v-model, because is more easy to get with it.

We also want to increase the specifications to add new features, if we have time.

I cannot get a pic picture, how i build the bibliography for my case with the problem solving circle, where i should start.

Comment: Unclear what you want: You want a list of primary sources like books/articles (bibliography) about the Problem Solving Cycle concept, that you will use to describe your new engineering process, while you write a thesis about a new product. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v-model gives emphasis to “Verification and Validation”. I don't necessarily agree with

> more easy to get with it

considering it's an extension to waterfall with a more complex process

There's different takes you can go about structuring the thesis. I suggest you to follow the molds of a use case study or the creation of a digital artifact. Based in the later, which seems to suit your case better, your work could be structured in the following manner

1. Introduction
2. State of the art
3. Model
4. Verification and Validation
5. Conclusion
6. Bibliography

The bibliography would be handy for you all the way through since you can learn from other people (books, articles, tweets, interviews, Q&As etc.) in each section. In more detail

- In section 2, you could be explain how that hardware is used, how that software is used, how the combo of the two is used. For instances, mine was about Immersive Big Data Visualization and this section was dedicated to explaining Big Data, Information Visualization,  Immersive Visualization and Immersive Big Data Visualization. All the way through referencing other authors and even for their acquisition I've used a specific strategy. If that comes in handy for you, a great way to visualize the bibliography in this level was through data from [Dimensions](https://www.dimensions.ai/) and visualize it using tools like [CiteSpace](http://cluster.cis.drexel.edu/%7Ecchen/citespace/) or [VOSViewer](https://www.vosviewer.com/).
- In section 3, you could explain the model (with references) you'd be using and raise up the Requirements, the System Analysis, the Software Design, ... as well as defining the Acceptance Testing, System Testing, ... For instances, your Software Design could be a merge between two already existing ones and slightly adapting them, so that way you'd need to reference both too in the bibliography. In my particular case, I took inspiration from two already existing pipelines and adapted for my particular case, removing some unnecessary stages.
- In section 4, you'd be coding and showing what you built passes all the tests in each level. Even for here you might require bibliography to get some specific practical cases as source of inspiration. I suggest the coding samples to be added in attachments as it can escalate greatly increase the number of pages.